# Excel Copy a sheet with its code to a new xls file

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

Please, could you tell me if the following is possible in VBA:

I need to write code that copies a sheet from my workbook to a new freshly created xls file. **BUT**, the sheet I wanna copy has a Macro behind (it's actually a WorkSheet_Change event handler) that I also want to copy to the new file.

Many thanks

Kind regards,

Miloud B

Comment: Did you try it ?  Copying the sheet also copies the code in its module...

Comment: Yep tried this. But it didn't copy the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `Export` the code from the original and then `Import` it into the copy.

Here's an article that shows some code for doing this: [Macro to Add a Macro to New Workbooks](http://www.mrexcel.com/articles/copy-vba-module.php)